# vba 7 - retrieving values from RegQueryValueEx returns unicode string

Tags: vba, api, winapi, unicode, ms-word

I cant figure out why i get back a unicode string with extra character per letter

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function RegQueryValueEx Lib "advapi32.dll"
Alias "RegQueryValueExA" (ByVal hKey As LongPtr, ByVal lpValueName As String,
                          ByVal lpReserved As LongPtr, lpType As LongPtr,
                          lpData As Any, lpcbData As LongPtr) As LongPtr


If RegQueryValueEx(hKey, strValueName, 0, dwType,
                   ByVal RegData, lDataBufSize) = ERROR_SUCCESS Then
End If
```

RegData has the following value "Mobile Address Book"
but if you paste that in notepad you will see all the extra characters. Do i need to convert the string to ascii?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA uses Unicode strings, but you are calling the **Ansi** version of `RegQueryValueEx()` (`RegQueryValueExA`) instead of the **Unicode** version (`RegQueryValueExW`).  But in both cases, the 5th parameter will receive raw Ansi/Unicode data (depending on version called) and the 6th parameter is expressed in **bytes**, not in **characters**.  So you have to account for that.  You also have to account for the fact that `Declare` in VBA always converts `String` values to Ansi, never to Unicode.  To work with Unicode APIs using Unicode strings in VBA, have a look at the following article for hints:

[VBA: Unicode Strings and the Windows API](http://blog.nkadesign.com/2013/vba-unicode-strings-and-the-windows-api/)

For example:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function RegQueryValueEx Lib "advapi32.dll"
Alias "RegQueryValueExW" (ByVal hKey As LongPtr, ByVal lpValueName As LongPtr,
                          ByVal lpReserved As LongPtr, lpType As LongPtr,
                          ByVal lpData As LongPtr, lpcbData As LongPtr) As LongPtr


If RegQueryValueEx(hKey, StrPtr(strValueName), 0, dwType,
                   StrPtr(RegData), lDataBufSize) = ERROR_SUCCESS Then
End If
```

Just make sure that `RegData` is pre-allocated to the required number of **Unicode characters** needed to receive the Unicode text, and that `lDataBufSize` is initialized with the number of **bytes** allocated in `RegData` so `RegQueryValueExW()` knows how many characters it can write into `RegData`.

**Update**: to read binary data:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function RegQueryValueEx Lib "advapi32.dll"
Alias "RegQueryValueExW" (ByVal hKey As LongPtr, ByVal lpValueName As LongPtr,
                          ByVal lpReserved As LongPtr, lpType As LongPtr,
                          lpData As Byte, lpcbData As LongPtr) As LongPtr


Dim RegData() As Byte
...
If RegQueryValueEx(hKey, StrPtr(strValueName), 0, dwType,
                   RegData(0), lDataBufSize) = ERROR_SUCCESS Then
End If
```

Comment: I had another question. I am trying to read REG_BINARY data from registry using ReqQueryValueExW. I get back a longptr, but i need to pass a byte array to a c++ dll function. How can I create a  byte array from a longptr?

Comment: `RegQueryValueEx()` does not return a longptr. You have to allocate the byte array and pass it to `RegQueryValueEx()`, you just have to change the declaration of `RegQueryValueEx()` to account for that.

Comment: Thanks remy! I got that figured out this morning :)

Comment: When would you use your update (byte data) instead of your first example (LongPtr)? What if you don't know what type the value has?

Comment: @johnywhy You can call `RegQueryValueEx()` to query the value's type using the `lpType` parameter, and then act accordingly by calling `RegQueryValueEx()` again with a suitable buffer to receive the actual data as needed. [Read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regqueryvalueexw)